# Blockcypher new transaction request returning more than input and output

Tags: testnet, blockcypher

I am new to Bitcoin and Blockchain, and Blockcypher..

I am trying to use Blockcypher APIs to create (and sign) and send a transaction (on testnet). The request i provide has 1 input and 1 output, but the response i receive has **2** inputs/outputs/tosign 50% of the time.. Why would this be? Thanks

Sample Request:

Posting to https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/new?token=XXXXXXXX

```
{
    "double_spend": false,
    "inputs": [{
        "addresses": ["mqtDjKw8wCyPBvk61NfkgmNFZDwHvCJTUD"]
    }],
    "outputs": [{
        "value": 2,
        "addresses": ["tb1qfefhgu4npfqjk36v66eqk6ee0gska720j09nvr"]
    }]
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "tx": {
        "hash": "b520ccb4b9ab96075c3cf1a91b0c7710a22332f0bb4d25409bcf9693a35477dd",
        "block_height": -1,
        "addresses": ["mqtDjKw8wCyPBvk61NfkgmNFZDwHvCJTUD", "tb1qfefhgu4npfqjk36v66eqk6ee0gska720j09nvr"],
        "total": 55000,
        "fees": 30000,
        "relayed_by": "35.226.46.118",
        "received": "2021-07-22T10:19:47.853381661Z",
        "ver": 1,
        "vin_sz": 2,
        "vout_sz": 2,
        "confirmations": 0,
        "preference": "high",
        "double_spend": false,
        "inputs": [{
            "prev_hash": "34e749b34cc75b996e7b28638cc4648958942b046bf9961837af7ab0046e53d1",
            "output_index": 0,
            "output_value": 10000,
            "addresses": ["mqtDjKw8wCyPBvk61NfkgmNFZDwHvCJTUD"],
            "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
        }, {
            "prev_hash": "106ad632e2474e683b2180181c1b911bc4d5727db5ab341ee8aded3b78fb2da7",
            "output_index": 1,
            "output_value": 75000,
            "addresses": ["mqtDjKw8wCyPBvk61NfkgmNFZDwHvCJTUD"],
            "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
        }],
        "outputs": [{
            "value": 2,
            "script": "00144e537472b30a412b474cd6b20b6b397a216ef94f",
            "addresses": ["tb1qfefhgu4npfqjk36v66eqk6ee0gska720j09nvr"],
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash"
        }, {
            "value": 54998,
            "script": "76a91471b6e0ce39475cbe5cd43966f5c7eb80a886952088ac",
            "addresses": ["mqtDjKw8wCyPBvk61NfkgmNFZDwHvCJTUD"],
            "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
        }]
    },
    "tosign": ["c0859bbf0f964af14c01d9ff2da9e5254279d02c5c75c902e3a8180db6bb67e5", "91a6c5b3003047c0af81348f12867918ebc4efd70f3ff1a5ee9e4566bf361de8"],
    "signatures": [],
    "pubkeys": []
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Without actually studying your data, it seems to me that as Its possible for an address to have multiple UTXOs and for a transaction amount to require using two of those, the second output would be change -- does this make sense to you?

Comment: Nope :) Not really, but there a few things for me to go on there thanks. What would be great to understand in short term is if this response is valid (sure it is) and that i can proceed with signing.

Comment: Also, if u had a min to look at data, that would REALLY help me. The only thing i can deduce, is that the second output has a value of 2, which maps to my requested value. Not sure what other amounts relate to. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Not sure what other amounts relate to.**

```
    "total": 55000,
```

The amount being transferred to outputs in this transaction

```
    "fees": 30000,
```

The difference between total input amounts  and total output amounts.

Note that the above two values sum to 85000.

```
        "output_value": 10000,
```

An amount associated with one UTXO with the specified spending address

```
        "output_value": 75000,
```

An amount associated with a second UTXO with the specified spending address

Note that the above two values sum to 85000.

```
        "value": 2,
```

The amount you specified be sent to the destination address

```
        "value": 54998,
```

The remainder of the 55000 ("total", see above) being returned as change.

Comment: Thats fantastic!! Thanks for stepping thru that